# ChartJS doesn't draw the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

Actually i've been trying for days to load data from ajax to a chart using ChartJS library but the issue was that the legend in another div was loaded the data from ajax was loaded right but the chart was like "invisible" when the canvas was created.

Now i was just trying to create a simple chart with static data from an json array
but i'm having still the same issue, the legend is shown but the chart isn't.

The issue maybe should be that in type i get "type is not defined"? If it's that how could i fix it?

I'd attach two screen one from debug of the array and another of the type value

[image]
[image]

While here is the JQuery code

```
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/light-bootstrap-dashboard.js?v=2.0.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/gabservizi.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
        LoadChart();
    });
    function LoadChart() {
        $("#dvChart").html("");
        $("#dvLegend").html("");

        //Populate data for the chart
        var fruits = new Array();

        var mango = {};
        mango.text = "Mango";
        mango.value = 20;
        mango.color = "#FEBD01";
        fruits.push(mango);

        var orange = {};
        orange.text = "Orange";
        orange.value = 40;
        orange.color = "#FF8C00";
        fruits.push(orange);

        var peach = {};
        peach.text = "Peach";
        peach.value = 55;
        peach.color = "#FFCBA6";
        fruits.push(peach);

        var el = document.createElement('canvas');
        $("#dvChart")[0].appendChild(el);

        var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: fruits
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
            var div = $("<div />");
            div.css("margin-bottom", "10px");
            div.html("<span style = 'display:inline-block;height:10px;width:10px;background-color:" + fruits[i].color + "'></span> " + fruits[i].text);
            $("#dvLegend").append(div);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: @Vel https://jsfiddle.net/cby9q1jz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
fruits.push(peach);

chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: fruits.map(f => f.text),
        datasets: [{ 
            data: fruits.map(f => f.value),
            backgroundColor: fruits.map(f => f.color)
        }]
    }
});
```

As far as I could tell, Chart.js always requires labels.

Answer (score 0):

The legend is not shown, you created your own legend by the data you have.

ChartJS normally draws it's own legend inside the `<canvas>` element. And within the options you have the ability to turn them off, which you haven't. So no legend and no chart of the framework is shown.

Anyway; you can use this to use your own legend and hide the framework's legend

```
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

Your chart doesn't show up, because your datastructure doesn't fit the datastructure required by chartjs.

See: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure

Keep in mind that a Pie/Doughnut do have an other data/label structure than line/bar charts